# node discord js export a function

Tags: function, sequelize.js, export, discord.js

I've been making a discord.js bot following the [official guide](https://discordjs.guide).
I have all my commands in the `/commands` folder as advised.

Then I followed the course to create a currency system with sequelize, following [this page](https://discordjs.guide/sequelize/currency.html) from the same guide.

I have a `balance.js` file inside the commands folder, but when I'm calling it, it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: currency.getBalance is not a function
```

I've defined the function in my `app.js` file, but how can I export it (or use it) inside the `balance.js` which is called by the `app.js` file?

This is the function defined in the main file `app.js`:

```
Reflect.defineProperty(currency, 'getBalance', {
    value: function getBalance(id) {
        const user = currency.get(id);
        return user ? user.balance : 0;
    },
});
```

This is `balance.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'balance',
    description: 'Informs you about your balance.',
    cooldown : 10,
    guildOnly : true,
    aliases: ['bal', 'cur', 'gem', 'gems'],
    execute(message, args) {
        const Discord = require('discord.js');
        const { Users, CurrencyShop, UserItems, CardBase, UserCollec } = require('../dbObjects');
        const currency = require('../app.js')

        async () => { const storedBalances = await Users.findAll();
    storedBalances.forEach(b => currency.set(b.user_id, b));
    UserCollec.sync(); }
        
        const target = message.author;
        return message.channel.send(`${target} has ${currency.getBalance(target.id)}<:Gem:756059891465977886>`);
        
    },
};
```

EDIT:

I progressed. Now I understand that I have to import the `currency` variable, which has been declared as a `new Discord.Collection()` in `app.js`.

I need to refer to this variable in a module and this module doesn't seem to see it as a collection. How do I import it?

Comment: I recommend changing `const currency = new Discord.Collection()` to `client.currency = new Discord.Collection()`. This way you can access the collection wherever you can access the client object. So in your command, you can use `message.client.currency`

Comment: Did you really fix up all of my bad and amateur english ?
I've been surprised.
Thx anw :) I'll test it as soon as I can.